# Write list values to CSV as they pertain to current iteration

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a list to a csv file such that the it comes out looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwRP4.png)
I'm sure I'm not using the CSV library correctly since it prints each character of just the first link to the file Here's my code:

```
for t in terms:
    fields = ["Search Term", "URL"]
    url = f"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={t}&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"
    html_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.find_all("item"):
        link= str(item)
        i = link.find("<link/>")
        j = link.find("<guid")
        links = link[i+7:j]
        with open("urls.csv", "w") as f:
            write = csv.writer(f)
            write.writerow(fields)
            write.writerows(links)
```

Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `xml` parser when creating the `soup`:

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

terms = ["refrigerator", "kitchen sink"]

with open("urls.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Search Term", "URL"])
    for t in terms:
        url = f"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={t}&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"
        print(f"Getting {url}")
        html_page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, "xml")
        for item in soup.find_all("link"):
            writer.writerow([t, item.get_text(strip=True)])
```

Creates `urls.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]